# Regex to include one (lowercase, uppercase, number, given special characters) in c# Azure function

Tags: c#, regex, azure, passwords, azure-functions

I am writing a Azure function which is in c# language. Now I want to generate a password which contains one (lowercase, uppercase, number and given special character).

I am using [Fare](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fare/1.0.3) in Azure function for c#

Azure function:-

```
using Fare;

var regex=@"/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,30}$/";

var xeger = new Xeger(regex);
var result = xeger.Generate();
log.Info("result" + result);
```

Error:-

```
2017-08-30T10:20:12.045 exceptionSystem.InvalidOperationException: state
   at Fare.Xeger.Generate(StringBuilder builder, State state)
   at Fare.Xeger.Generate()
   at Submission#0.<Run>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerCSharp1\run.csx:line 13

2017-08-30T10:03:28.989 Exception while executing function: Functions.HttpTriggerCSharp1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. Fare: state.
```

Error on Line no 13 is var regex=...

Kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: What type of pattern (for which regex engine) does the Xeger accept? Your pattern contains lookaheads, I think these are not supported. Try `var regex=@"^[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,30}$";`, does it generate the results as expected?

Comment: *One or more errors occurred* So what were the errors? Does the exception have inner exceptions?

Comment: @DavidG I see one or more errors only.

Comment: And `InnerException` property is null?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Still I see same error when I use var regex=@"^[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,30}$";

Comment: @DavidG Where InnerException is available? I haven't print any exception

Comment: Your log has "Exception while executing function..." which means you have an exception. Try catching it and logging the full details.

Comment: @DavidG I see this 2017-08-30T10:20:12.045 exceptionSystem.InvalidOperationException: state
   at Fare.Xeger.Generate(StringBuilder builder, State state)
   at Fare.Xeger.Generate()
   at Submission#0.<Run>d__1.MoveNext() in D:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerCSharp1\run.csx:line 13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception comes from this part `[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]` that characters after `\d` makeing exceptions. just change it to `0-9` if you want to match a digit; something like :`[A-Za-z0-9#$@!%&*?]` or moving it to end like `[A-Za-z#$@!%&*?\d]`.
But your complex regex will result after a long time ;).

> Note: There are some rare results of using `\d` inside `[..]` ;).

A better regex for your need, I think can be something like this:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[#$@!%&*?]).{8,}
```

Explanation:

```
(?=.*\d)           => there is at least one digit
(?=.*[a-z])        => there is at least one lowercase character
(?=.*[A-Z])        => there is at least one uppercase character
(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])   => there is at least one special character
.{8,}              => length is 8 or more
```

Comment: I get output as 5;⊳2侢실詼ಥ꣭&갇㈶ਝ莂2༜쬚㻥7<貒4=熔铦ב6몴D今
퓡粢䲉lUᖚ==ijJꐈꞍp엹귿O괭v猙kX㙶ꁾujI졩䝮漂䤫j=Kꄢ疉YL=@ቻ曪ߍ℻艹Ꜽ

Comment: yes. exception solved. I need password string based on regex, but i get invalid characters as mentioned earlier.

Comment: I see! But it is another question, please ask it in another question, I'm not so familiar to Xeger options ;).